# Handling <a> click events as Google Analytics events

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to send events with the GA tag when a user clicks  tags with certain properties (e.g., 'tel:' link, '.zip' extension), but having issues with the binding/unbinding of the anchor.

GA doesn't send an event unless I intercept the click also, which explains why I'm doing it this way. I couldn't find a surefire example online anywhere.

```
$('a').on('click', function( event ) {

    $linkObj = $( this );

    // Get element attributes
    href = $linkObj.attr('href') + '';

    // Safety check
    if ( !href || href === undefined || typeof href === 'undefined' ) {
        href = '';
    }

    // If link is telephone number
    try {

        if ( href.substring(0, 4) === 'tel:' ) {

            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

            sendEvent( 'call', 'click', href.split( 'tel:' )[ 1 ] + '' );

            $linkObj.unbind( 'click' ).click();

            // this doesn't seem to re-enable to <a> as clickable
            setTimeout ( function () { 
                $linkObj.bind( 'click' ).click(); 
            }, 100 );

        }
    catch (e) {
        console.log ('err: ', e );

});

var sendEvent = function ( category, action, label, value ) {
    ga( 'send', 'event', category, action, label, value );
};
```

Comment: is the url builder something you can utilize? https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery you can use the 'attribute ends with' or 'attribute contains' selectors:

```
jQuery("[href$='zip'] ,[href*='tel:']").click(function () {
 // do the analytics
}
```

This will only return zip- and tel- Links in the first place so you do not need any custom "safety checks".